# How can I use html elements with css animation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to use the '@keyframes' Css element and implement html elements within the curly braces to get an animation? I've been working on a rock paper scissors project where you click the button and it'll run through a 5 second animation, before randomly landing on one of the hand signs. my current code for the html and javascript is this:

```
 <h1 id="pageTitle">Rock - Paper - Scissors!</h1>

<div class="container">
<div class="box" id="box">

</div>
  
  <span></span> 
</div> 
<button class="button" id="Shoot" onclick="shoot()">RPS Shoot!</button>
```

```
var rpsArr = [
      "<div class='rock'><div class='rockhand rockPointerFinger'></div><div class='rockhand rockMiddleFinger'></div><div class='rockhand rockRingFinger'></div><div class='rockhand rockPinkyFinger'></div><div class='rockhand rockThumb'></div><div class='rockhand rockPalm'></div></div>",
      '<div class="scissors scissorsPointerFinger"></div><div class="scissors scissorsMiddleFinger"></div><div class="scissors scissorsRingFinger"></div><div class="scissors scissorsPinkyFinger"></div><div class="scissors scissorsThumb"></div><div class="scissors scissorsPalm"></div>', 
      '<div class="paper paperPointerFinger"> <div class="paperPointBackground"></div></div><div class="paper paperMiddleFinger"><div class="paperMidBackground"></div></div><div class="paper paperRingFinger"><div class="paperRingBackground"></div></div><div class="paper paperPinkyFinger"><div class="paperPinkyBackground"></div></div> <div class="paper paperThumb"><div class="paperThumbBackground"></div></div><div class="paper paperPalm"><div class="paperPalmBackground"></div></div>'
    ];

/*Function that runs animation then ends on one of the hands in to the box as a final result */

function shoot() {
   document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 
   "<style>.box{animation-name:rps; animation-duration: 5seconds;} @keyframes: rps {0% {;} 10% {;} 20% {;} 40% {;} 60% {;} 80 {;} 100% {;}}</style>
    rpsArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * rpsArr.length)];"
  };
```

I'm sure I can just make images of each hand sign and this would be easier, but I want to do this using the div elements within the array.

I've tried using a script that would input the array elements one at a time via a basic loop, but it stalls without the animation then after 5 minutes just produces the end, which is a random selection of one of the hand signs. And that didn't work.

and any animation help I've looked up only talks about transforming elements by changing their size, color, or moving them across the screen. And since I'm not trying to transform these elements it doesn't help or translate well for the intended goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP, you can see the snippet below for how I would approach this problem.  @Yogi's suggestion may also be good, but I am not very familiar with the new animation APIs and don't really know if swapping elements in and out would be an appropriate use case or not.

```js
var visibleIdx = 0;

var options = document.getElementsByClassName("option");

var startTime = 0;


function shoot() {
    startTime = Date.now();
    
  loopUntilTime(startTime + 5000);
  document.getElementById("filler").classList.toggle("tickdown");
};

function loopUntilTime(endTime){
    var newIdx;
  do {
    newIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  while (newIdx === visibleIdx);
  options[visibleIdx].style.display = "none";
  visibleIdx = newIdx;
  options[visibleIdx].style.display="";
  
  if (Date.now() < endTime)
  {
    setTimeout(() => loopUntilTime(endTime), 300);
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("filler").classList.toggle("tickdown");
  }
}
```

```css
#progressBar{
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

#filler{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}


.tickdown{
  animation: countdown 5s linear;
}

@keyframes countdown{
  from{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  50%{
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
 <h1 id="pageTitle">Rock - Paper - Scissors!</h1>

 <div class="container">
   <div class="box" id="box">
     <div class="option" style="display: none">
       Rock
     </div>
     <div class="option" style="display: none">
       Scissors
     </div>
     <div class="option" style="display: none">
       Paper
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
 <button class="button" id="Shoot" onclick="shoot()">RPS Shoot!</button>
 <div id="progressBar">
   <div id="filler">
     
   </div>
 </div>
```

In short, I would not try to use CSS `animation` to swap different DOM elements in and out.  If you wanted to use a single element with different `background-images` for your rock, paper, and scissors, that might be more manageable, but since you have completely different divs for each, I think a JS solution is more appropriate.  Also, hot-swapping in a new `<style>` element as a response to a mouse-click in order to trigger an animation is pretty sketchy and will be hard to maintain or debug later on.

If you have additional questions around this problem, I am happy to help, but please first edit your post to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (or in this case, just a working example in general), preferably formatted as a StackSnippet (the `<>` icon in the toolbar).  Be sure to include your CSS so that we can actually run your code and see what you are seeing.

Comment: This actually did everything I was trying to do. I swapped out the words with the hand sign emoji's and just have to mess with their CSS values so they fit in the box better. But regardless this was the biggest hurdle for this project and your solution worked out perfectly. I seriously can't thank you enough and am gonna def be spending a few days breaking down this solution so I can retain it.

Everything from here on out is honestly just cosmetics. Again thank you for your help.